# HTML5 Synchronization Between User and Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I am trying to create a HTML5 app that will allow an user to automatically upload files from a user's computer to my server (similar to Dropbox for Windows where file transfers are updated between computer and server in the background).

The user will have around 100+ .csv files in a single folder. The HTML5 app will ask the user to select the folder. Afterwards, the files will be uploaded to the server in the background.

Is this possible in HTML5 using WebSockets or FileStream? Any advice will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Browsers are very picky about security with local files.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using JWebSocket framework.Visit https://jwebsocket.org/. it has got lot of plug-ins and one such plug-in is FileUpload plug-in.http://enapso.org/jwsForum219/posts/list/59.page.Hope this will help you.